# Disable the ternary (?:) operator in C# with Visual Studio or ReSharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, ternary-operator

I have come to consider the ternary operator as undesirable for two reasons:

- Cannot break on the branches of the statement
- Even worse, coverage tools such as nCrunch will give the impression that the statement is covered if just one of the branches is covered

The only case where I ever use it now is for a simple assignment with expression (non-calculated values), e.g. `var a = condition ? "yes" : "no"`

It would be nice to have a way to tell ReSharper to stop suggesting the operator unless it is a very simple case like this.

It would be nicer to have ReSharper suggesting to *remove* them when the statements are too complex (i.e. more than expressions).

I also wonder if there is a way to completely disable a language construct from MSBuild perspective?

All of this would of course be mainly useful if it could be shared through source control to the whole team.

Comment: You might be able to write a new rule for FxCop that does this...

Comment: I bet a R# extension could do both your 'nice' and 'nicer'